# Geometry of the feature getting deleted after UpdateCursor

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, geometry, cursor

I am making a script which calculates numerous indices for each building. Here  I am trying to get the area a 100 buffer around the building and the area of buildings intersecting with the buffer. Now while am using arcpy.da.UpdateCursor for iterating through each feature, once i run the script,the **polygons just vanish**. I don't want them to disappear. The attribute table is still there but no geometry.

How can I resolve this?

I am using ArcMap 10.4.

Input Details:

- Building_Sample: polygon shapefile where areas are to be added in
  attribute table
- Original_Footprints: same building shapefile but with
  surrounding areas for intersection calculations

The calculations calculations include:

1. Area of 100m buffer of the selected building (which is getting iterated)
2. Area of builtup within the Buffer (Calculated by intersecting buffer with Original_Footprints
3. Counting number of buildings within 100m distance of the selected building
4. Sum of area of all those buildings
5. Area of the Convex Hull surrounding all those buildings
6. Sum of distance to each of these building from the selected building
7. Sum of square of distance to each of these building from the selected building

I want these values for each building in their attributes, hence the use of UpdateCursor. I am not sure if i can do steps 3-7 overall without using any iterations.

Updated Code:

```
import arcpy
import datetime

# Setting up the Environment
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/DPR/Thesis programming/GIS/Pythonoutputs/pytry.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True

# Script arguments
Building_Sample = "del" 
Original_Footprints = "Simple_Build"
Buffer_Distance = "100 Meters"

# Local variables:
fields = ["OID@","SHAPE@","BufArea","Buf","Build_No","BuildBufAr","ConHullAr","BuildLen","BuildLensq"]
OGlyr = "Original_Footprints_layer"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Original_Footprints,OGlyr)
Start = datetime.datetime.now()
print(Start)
print "OID@","      ","SHAPE@", "BufArea", "Buf", "Build_No", "BuildBufAr", "ConHullAr", "BuildLen", "BuildLensq"

# Process: Iterate Feature Selection
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(Building_Sample, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:

            BufferSHP = "in_memory/Buffer"
            # Process: Buffer
            arcpy.Buffer_analysis(row[1], BufferSHP, Buffer_Distance)

            #Finde area of the buffer
            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(BufferSHP, "SHAPE@AREA")  as cursori:
                for rowi in cursori:

                  row[3] = int(rowi[0])
                  
            #print("buffer"+str(row[3]))
            

            # Process: Intersect
            INSECBUFFER = arcpy.Intersect_analysis([BufferSHP,Original_Footprints], arcpy.Geometry(), "ONLY_FID", "0.00 Meters", "INPUT")

            #Find total area of intersected buildings 
            Area = sum([g.area for g in INSECBUFFER])
            
            row[2] = int(Area)
           
            #print("Insecarea" + str(row[2]))


            # Process: Select Layer By Location
            arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(OGlyr, "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE", row[1], Buffer_Distance, "NEW_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")

            #Count Number of buildings in selection
            row[4]=arcpy.GetCount_management(OGlyr)

            #print("Count" + str(row[4]))

            #Get Building areas in the search radius
            BuildAr = 0
            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(OGlyr, "SHAPE@AREA")  as cursork:
               for rowk in cursork:
                   BuildAr = BuildAr + rowk[0]

            row[5] = int(BuildAr)

            #print("area" + str(row[5]))


            #Get Area of Convex Hul polygon
            Hull = "in_memory/Hull"
            arcpy.MinimumBoundingGeometry_management(OGlyr, Hull, "CONVEX_HULL", "ALL", "", "MBG_FIELDS")
            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Hull, "SHAPE@AREA")  as cursorl:
                for rowl in cursorl:

                  row[6] = int(rowl[0])

            #print("Conhul " + str(row[6]))


            # Get sum of Distance of each building to the center one
            row[7] = int(sum([f[0].distanceTo(row[1]) for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(OGlyr, "SHAPE@")]))
            row[8] = int(sum([(f[0].distanceTo(row[1])*f[0].distanceTo(row[1])) for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(OGlyr, "SHAPE@")]))
            
            #print("Distance" + str(row[7]))
            #print("Distancesq" + str(row[8]))

            #Print table
            print row[0],"      ", row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8]

            if (int(row[0]) % 100) == 0:
                print datetime.datetime.now(), "      ", row[0]
            
            cursor.updateRow(row)

Final = (datetime.datetime.now())
Elapsed = Final - Start
print(Final)
print(Elapsed)

arcpy.Delete_management(in_memory, "Workspace")
```

Comment: There `row[2]` would refer to the 3rd field `"BufArea"` won't it? I thought numbering started with 0, 1, 2

Comment: Yes. I think you should use one Buffer and [Intersect](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/intersect.htm) instead of nesting cursors. Afterwards you can read the result and update the fields using da.UpdateCursor.

Comment: I cant use 1 buffer and intersect, as i have to iterate through each building seperately, and there are further calculations for each building, which is why am including `SHAPE@` in fields for update cursor

Comment: Yes you can, have a good look at fields in intersect output and use summary statistics.

Comment: I have edited the post to include the further calculations. If there are other tools i can use to calculate those values as well without iterations, it would be helpful to know. But the main issue still stands that why the geometry of the feature is getting deleted even though i am not updating it.

Comment: What is the value of the `row` variable after you have executed your code? `type(row[1])`

Comment: I have not changed anything in that field, i dont want to change it, but still want to access it for other processes (buffer, create layer file, and calculate sum of distances processes)

Comment: What helps to troubleshoot, whether with the vendor or communities like SE, is to create the [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  I would start at the end of your loop and work backwards dropping sections of code to see if/when the issue goes away (of course, leave the updateCursor call).

Comment: That's really nice @bixb0012. I'll try to make one and add in the question as well.  I am new to programming so it helps to know such practices! Thanks  a lot :D